# StanfordCoreNLP: Why multiple roots for SemanticGraph (e.g. dependency parsing)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

In the the definition of the SemanticGraph class which is being used for Dependency Parsing.

Here is the definition of the variable "roots" as a collection of vertices:

```
private final Collection<IndexedWord> roots;
```

My question is why *collection*? In what cases we would need more than one vertex as the root?

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all honesty, SemanticGraph has a lot of historical code which was motivated by its initial use in an RTE (Recognizing Textual Entailment) system, not for syntactic dependency parsing, so don't read too much into it all. But, nevertheless, there are various fairly natural use cases (e.g., fragment parsing or the output of semantic graph transformation operations) which can result in disconnected graphs, and, hence, multiple roots.

Comment: Thanks Chris for elaboration. Could you give an example sentence for which your Dependency Parse returns fragmented graphs (given only one sentence)?

Comment: This doesn't happen ... or shouldn't. Our dependency parses should always be connected.